# Несколько вариантов десериализации JSON. Как правильно оформить?

Tags: c#, json, шаблоны-проектирования

Есть некоторое API, которое я хочу реализовать на C#.
Распишу мой вопрос на примере одного из запросов, который создает ордер на продажу валюты.

Запрос возвращает ответ в виде Json, и передает всегда 2 параметра.
Если запрос удался, то Success = 1 и Тело с параметрами открытого ордера Словарь(Key-value).

Если же, например, не хватает валюты или какая-то другая причина то вернется Success = 0 и строка (String) с пояснением ошибки.

Соответственно, есть два класса POJO: Error и Complete (Для понятности)
Других вариантов ответа быть не может в моём случае, но бывает всякое, поэтому задаю этот вопрос. А вопрос в следующем:

Как правильно десериализовать полученный ответ?

Задаюсь этим вопросом, так как заранее я не могу знать какому объекту присваивать результат от запроса.

В голову приходит через try/catch попробовать десериализовать сначала с Complete, в случае ошибки десериализовывать в Error. Но получается откровенный колхоз! А если вариантов ответа будет больше?

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это делается по человечески?

UPD:

Решение нашлось!
Сначала нужно десериализовать в объект, содержащий

```
int success;
object responce;
```

Проверить success и в зависмости от результата, десериализовать в нужны объект!

UPD2:

Всё гениальное - просто!
Нужно расширить класс-модель полем error и смело десериализовать.
В зависимости от результата заполнятся нужные поля.

Comment: Какой http код ответа если `Success = 0`?

Comment: При Success = 0 код ответа 200, Т.к. сам запрос отправлен и ответ получен успешно. Success = 0 бывает когда заявка на открытие ордера не была создана на сервере.

Comment: Тогда нужно видеть примеры ответов сервера.

Comment: Если внутренний объект отличается, то надо искать некие "опорные точки", по которым будет идти десериализация в класс. Вот возьмем, к примеру исключения в C#, вам дают `
NullReferenceException` и вы сразу понимаете, "ага, где-то NULL!", также и тут, если вам сервер отдает, например `"Message" : "SuccessPayment"`, то вы уже понимаете, что это за объект пришел, а значит его можно смело десериализовать в нужный тип. Если же у вас поэтому API приходит одно и тоже, но часть скрыта, то это один класс с Nullable свойствами.  Так что тут все зависит от структуры, которую вы нам не показываете.

Comment: Хорошо бы уточнить, какую именно библиотеку для работы с json используете. Или можете использовать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение нашлось! Сначала нужно десериализовать в объект, содержащий

```
int success;
object responce;
```

Проверить success и в зависмости от результата, десериализовать в нужны объект!

Answer (score 2):

> Если запрос удался, то Success = 1 ...
> Если же, например, не хватает валюты или какая-то другая причина то вернется Success = 0 ...

Если вы отдаете json в ответ, то с ним вы отдаете и http `200 OK`, в обратном случае вы должны отдать ответ `400 Bad Request` и никаких Success не нужно.

Comment: Не я реализовываю API и повлиять на него не в моих силах( Я описал то, что мне доступно и с чем нужно работать

Answer (score 1):

Вариантов множество:

1. Например смотреть на код ответа сервера. если 200 = ОК, то сервер вернул внутри объект нужного типа. Если сервер вернул 400, тогда беда, произошла ошибка и нужно десериализовать объект с типом "ошибка".
2. Сервер меняет свойство Content-Type в зависимости от типа объекта в ответе. если там application-json - то десериализуем, если там там text/plain, то просто выводим текст ошибки куда необходимо.
3. Можно создать базовый класс и использовать отражение типа в одно из свойств в его наследников. Перед десериализацией находить/читать это свойство и создавать объект нужного типа.

   ```
    public abstract class PluginAdapter : IPluginAdapter
    {
        [DisplayName("Версия библиотеки"), Description("Отладочное свойство"), Category("Плагин")]
        public string Version => "1";
        [DisplayName("Тип данных"), Description("Отладочное свойство"), Category("Плагин")]

        public string typeFullName { get => this.GetType().FullName; set{} }

        [DisplayName("Сборка"), Description("Путь к файлу сборки"), Category("Плагин")]
        public string assemblyPath { get => GetType().Assembly.Location; set{}}}
   ```